# rails how to return parent's property as child's property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: recordType and record.

The recordType model has attributes: typeName, status.
The record model has attributes: applicant_id, complete.

RecordType has_many :records

Now, I want to list all records on a page. I do not want to send the recordType bundled with the record on each record. I want to be able to say record.typeName and get the recordType's typeName attribute.

Essentially, I want to emulate:

```
SELECT r.*, rt.typeName as typeName from records r 
INNER JOIN recordTypes rt on r.recordType_id = rt.id
```

in rails. I am new to rails, so I am unsure how to make this happen - Do I put in something in the model? Do I have to create a serializer? How do I return this parent's attribute in such a manner that the child can directly refer the attribute instead of going through the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `record` model, should have a `record_type_id` column in the database, so when you say `Record belongs_to :record_type` the association is made without errors. If you haven't just create a migration adding the column to the table and you are good to go.
Also you need to make a inverse association on `Record` model. You have a `has_many :records`, but you are lacking a `belongs_to :record_type`.
When you have the column, and the associations set, you can proceed to do something like this:

```
@record = Record.first
@record.record_type # It is a RecordType model
@record.record_type.typeName # Returns the string typeName
```

*** UPDATE ***

You can add a method to the `Record` class:

```
def typeName
  record_type.typeName if record_type
end
```

This way you can access with `@record.typeName`

Comment: I do have the id key associations and I've been able to get the typeName using record.record_type.typeName. What I want to be able to do is use record.typeName to get the typeName without having to go through record_type every time.

Comment: @Darshan You can define a method on `Record` that returns the typeName, see edit.

Comment: Ah nice! Follow up question: I'm using Rails purely as an API at this point and I need to send the record object to my front end. I'm not able to use the typeName method on the front end - how would I achieve the same thing on the front end? Is there no other way but to serialize it?

Comment: @Darshan Yeah, you can use a JSON generation gem like grape or jbuilder, which maps your model object to a JSON object.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much!